# How can I add text animation using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, animation, text, css-animations

I want that my text blinks at the rate of 2 times per second.

I tried but failed to get animated text!

Answer (score 1):

A necessary disclaimer: a flashing text/graphic is not a good idea especially for people suffering from photo-epileptic seizures, people  with vestibular disorders, or people with cognitive disabilities.

If you still want to blink the text you can use a simple animation that changes the opacity of an element but *only* for users that didn't choose any preference about reduced motion, e.g.

```css
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  :where(.blink) {
    animation: .5s blink 0s linear infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0, 100% { opacity: 1 }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<p class="blink">Blinking text</p>
```

if feasible, for accessibility reasons I'd suggest to set at least a finite and small `animation-iteration-count`, so that the text stops flashing after a short time.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>Blinking Text</p>
```

```css
p {
  animation:  0.5s blink linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's often helpful to provide context for your answer instead of simply providing a code block.